# Swift - using a Switch to change the function of a UIButton

Tags: arrays, swift, function, uibutton, switch-statement

I would like to know if it's possible to use a Switch(toggle button) to change the function of a UIButton?

Right now my UIButton deals 4 cards.  I'd like to use a Switch(toggle button) to make it pull cards from a different string array in order to deal a different selection of cards.

Right now I have managed to make it change label texts, background color or even have it deal different cards when its switched on and off.  But that's as far as I can get.

Thanks in advance for any help or guidance!

Comment: `@IBAction func dealCards(sender: UIButton) { if toggle { // pull from array1 } else { // pull from array2 }` It's not much different than changing a label text or background color.

Comment: Oh my god I can't believe I missed that!!  I'm brand new to swift so sorry about that.  I was trying to place my if/else statements in the switch IBAction instead of the uibutton action.

Comment: Do I even need the switch hooked up as an IBAction?  Can it sit there blank?

Comment: You'll need a reference to the switch so you can use either an IBOutlet or IBAction. For the outlet you can simply use 'if mySwitch.on { } else { }' (typed on my phone, can't put that in a block..).

Comment: Thank you very much.  I have it as both right now, I'll delete the IBAction.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer since comments is too limited for me to show how to do it more efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@IBOutlet weak var mySwitch: UISwitch!

var array1: [Cards] = []
var array2: [Cards] = []

@IBAction dealCards(sender: UIButton) {
    let cards = mySwitch.on ? array1 : array2

    // Do things with cards
}
```

Just a simple example of how to do it.

Comment: Right on, now I can vote you.  Your initial answer did the job anyway.  I still can't believe I was that close and didn't see it.  Trying to do it in my IBAction for my switch threw me right off! Hahaha

Comment: Thanks :). The initial solution will probably create unnecessary duplication of code. In this answer, you can use the same code by just changing the array. If you need to mutate your original array, you'll have to edit the code slightly.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah I need to go through my project soon and figure out how to slim it down I think.